# Docker dind access to DB container

Tags: java, spring, docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have got some issue. My task to implement the web system which will be able to compile java maven project, test under the hood and build a report whether all that stuff was done successfully.

So I need an isolated container to run JUnit tests inside my service to prevent illegal access from tested solution to my service host. In aim to make everrything secured. So what do I do: I have got docker-compose "cluster" with a database service and y web service. When my web service is requested (solution project is passed like zip achive of maven project folder) I create a new dind container with some util which connects to that DB service, downloads zip archive with solution, unzips it and performs `mvn clean compile`, `mvn test`, etc. It does not matter. It also puts some info to that DB about whether compilation was successful or not, also about testing. When I tested this with DB on `localhost:5432` (pg), it worked via  `--netwok=host` flag. Even DIND container cound access DB. But when I run everything in docker-compose and also DB is a docker-compose service, DIND container does not see DB host. Is it possible to access DB service from DIND container? May, it would be better solution?

PS: just right now I really think to implement all this stuff via volumes, but this approach has several significant drawbacks. First one is that isolation decreases. Second one is that we also need to unzip solution project somewhere onto the web service. But where? As for me, it looks weird:) But it will work 99%. Are there any other more appropriate solutions? Thanx

PPS: sorry for longread.

Comment: Can you fix the application under test to not require a database to be running for its unit tests?  Then running the application in a sibling container (without DinD) maybe with `--net=none` might be enough.  If that's not an option, it might help to [edit] the question to include a [mcve]; it's not clear to me which pieces are running in which container environment.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the container `localhost` is the same container.
If you have a docker-compose, you can use the service name to connect to another container.

For example, if you have service `db` and `app`, `app` can connect to `db:5432`